# Proof of limit of sum of series

Tags: real-analysis

I know that

$$\exp(-x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n+2}x^n}{n!}$$

converges for every positive $x$

Then we should have

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow+\infty}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n+2}x^n}{n!}=0$$

How can we prove the above result WITHOUT using the exponential function? I encoutered some similar situations where I have a series and I must calculate the limit of the sum. One of them is:

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow+\infty}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n+2}x^{n+1}}{n\cdot n!}$$

It's very helpful to solve one of them or both of them or all of them.

Comment: $(-1)^{n+2} = (-1)^n$; just saying.

Comment: I want to avoid $(-1)^0$ :-)

Comment: And why would you want to do that?

Answer (score 2):

This prof is based on differential equations.

Let $f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^nx^n/n!$. Then
$$
f'+f=0,\quad f(0)=1.
$$
The equation $y'+y=0$ satisfies the conditions of existence and uniqueness of solution. Since $y\equiv0$ is a solution, uniqueness implies that $f(x)>0$ for all $x>0$. Then $f'<0$,  $f$ is decreasing on $[0,\infty)$ and $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=a\ge0$ exists. Suposse $a>0$. Then we would have $f'(x)=-f(x)<-a$ for all $x>0$. The would imply that
$$
f(x)=1+\int_0^xf'(s)\,ds\le1-a\,x,
$$
in contradiction with the fact that $f(x)>0$ for all $x>0$.